# Parsing Odds From Website Problem in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, html-parsing

I'm trying to learn VBA to parse website information. Currently I'm trying to parse odds from a website, but shows me a error and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me?

**This is my code:**

```
Public Sub GetOddsInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, URL As String
    Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim headers()
    Dim linkgame, linkbtts, linkover As String
    Dim teams, oddHome, oddDraw, oddAway, oddBtts, oddNbtts, oddOver, oddUnder As String
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    URL = "https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/germany/2-bundesliga/results/#/page/3/"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1")
    headers = Array("Teams", vbNullString, "Home Odds", "Draw Odds", "Away Odds", "BTTS", _
                    "NBTTS", "O2.5", "U2.5")

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 URL

        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        For i = 0 To 1
        '.document.getElementsByClassName(" deactivate").Length -1
            .Navigate2 URL

            linkgame = .document.getElementsByClassName(" deactivate")(i).getElementsByClassName("name table-participant")(0).Children(0).href
            teams = .document.getElementsByClassName(" deactivate")(i).getElementsByClassName("name table-participant")(0).Children(0).innerText

            .Navigate2 linkgame

            oddHome = .document.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).getElementsByClassName("right")(0).innerText
            oddDraw = .document.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).getElementsByClassName("right")(1).innerText
            oddAway = .document.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).getElementsByClassName("right")(2).innerText

            linkbtts = linkgame & "#bts;2"
            .Navigate2 linkbtts

            oddBtts = .document.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).getElementsByClassName("right")(0).innerText
            oddNbtts = .document.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).getElementsByClassName("right")(1).innerText

            linkover = linkgame & "#over-under;2;2.50;0"
            .Navigate2 linkover

            oddOver = .document.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).getElementsByClassName("right")(1).innerText
            oddUnder = .document.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).getElementsByClassName("right")(2).innerText

            ws.Range("A" & i + 2) = teams
            ws.Range("C" & i + 2) = oddHome
            ws.Range("D" & i + 2) = oddDraw
            ws.Range("E" & i + 2) = oddAway
            ws.Range("F" & i + 2) = oddBtts
            ws.Range("G" & i + 2) = oddNbtts
            ws.Range("H" & i + 2) = oddOver
            ws.Range("I" & i + 2) = oddUnder
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Shows me error in `.Navigate2 linkgame` and I don't understand why since `linkgame` will be the link of the game.

Comment: Could you include the error message in your question? And can you dump out the value of linkgame?

Comment: how can i put the value of linkgame in my code?

Comment: Use either: debug.print linkgame, or MsgBox linkgame.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/q61nvq

Comment: the error says : "Error in time execution. The method 'Navigate2' of object 'IWebBrower2' failed"

Comment: Is the value of linkgame correct? It may be that Navigate2 can't use it. For example, is the URL an absolute path? Does it have HTTP or HTTPS protocol in the URL?

Comment: i think my linkgame is correct . Maybe the problem is Navigate2 , don't know why. The URL have HTTP like you can see on the print

Comment: You can try using Navigate instead and see what happens. Otherwise, try a different URL just for testing, something like .Navigate2 "https://www.google.com" and see if it works.

Comment: if i switch .Navigate2 "google.com" it works but now shows me error on "oddHome = .document.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).getElementsByClassName("right")(0).innerText"

Comment: I think you should fix your Navigate2 problem first. Does using Navigate instead of Navigate2 work with linkgame?

Comment: It would help to show what an example output couple of rows would look like. The re-write you show could have the selector methods optimized I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create the IE Object using the `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` method, and modify your code as below:

```
Public Sub GetOddsInfo()
    Dim IE As Object, URL As String
    Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim headers()
    Dim teams, oddHome, oddDraw, oddAway, oddBtts, oddNbtts, oddOver, oddUnder As String
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    URL = "https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/germany/2-bundesliga/results/#/page/3/"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1")
    headers = Array("Teams", vbNullString, "Home Odds", "Draw Odds", "Away Odds", "BTTS", _
                    "NBTTS", "O2.5", "U2.5")
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 URL

        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        For i = 0 To 1

    Dim linkgame, linkbtts, linkover As String
        '.document.getElementsByClassName("deactivate").Length -1

            .Navigate2 URL
            While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            linkgame = .document.getElementsByClassName("deactivate")(i).getElementsByClassName("name table-participant")(0).Children(0).href
            teams = .document.getElementsByClassName("deactivate")(i).getElementsByClassName("name table-participant")(0).Children(0).innerText

            .Navigate2 linkgame
            While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            oddHome = .document.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).getElementsByClassName("right")(0).innerText
            oddDraw = .document.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).getElementsByClassName("right")(1).innerText
            oddAway = .document.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).getElementsByClassName("right")(2).innerText

            linkbtts = linkgame & "#bts;2"

            .Navigate2 linkbtts
             While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend 

            oddBtts = .document.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).getElementsByClassName("right")(0).innerText
            oddNbtts = .document.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).getElementsByClassName("right")(1).innerText

            linkover = linkgame & "#over-under;2;2.50;0"

            .Navigate2 linkover

             While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            oddOver = .document.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).getElementsByClassName("right")(1).innerText
            oddUnder = .document.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).getElementsByClassName("right")(2).innerText

            ws.Range("A" & i + 2) = teams
            ws.Range("C" & i + 2) = oddHome
            ws.Range("D" & i + 2) = oddDraw
            ws.Range("E" & i + 2) = oddAway
            ws.Range("F" & i + 2) = oddBtts
            ws.Range("G" & i + 2) = oddNbtts
            ws.Range("H" & i + 2) = oddOver
            ws.Range("I" & i + 2) = oddUnder 
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

The output as below:

[image]

Comment: @QHarr, Thanks for reminding me about that, after removing them it is more readable.

Comment: sorry but now i saw one problem

Comment: when i'm trying to parse oddBtts, oddNbtts, oddOver and oddUnder it shows me basically the 1X2 odds

Comment: So i think the problem now is that ".document.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).getElementsByClassName("right")(0).innerText" isn't looking on the direct link (linkbtts or linkover). Is looking maybe in linkgame